# Grabbing only non-empty cells from a row range for every row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have a survey that sends responses into a Google sheet. The raw data that is inserted is messy, so I have another sheet that processes the incoming raw data.

One of the things I need to do is: from a range of columns in one row, pull the non-empty cells--and do this automatically with every new response that comes in.

This is what I've come up with that works with a single row, but I can't figure out how to have it automatically apply to the entire column:

```
=transpose(QUERY(unique(transpose({'Raw Data'!AL3:AY3,'Raw Data'!AL3:AY3})),
 "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 <> '' ORDER BY Col1 ASC LIMIT 8",0))
```

Because the survey will insert rows, it ends up adjusting any cell references in my 'Processed Data' sheet, so I've been trying to use `ARRAYFORMULA` unsuccessfully.

Also, the range of columns will be more than 400 (options of schools), so manually writing out individual column names would probably be unfeasible.

[Here's a link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KUir26QoYAcmr29hr_DzMOGVpkBt2g5IGfdN2JRDbXk/edit?usp=sharing)

The column of issue starts on column O

Background: In the survey, a respondent can select multiple schools to a maximum of 8 out of a selection of 400+ schools. In the 'Raw Data' sheet, each school option is represented by a column.

Hopefully all of that made sense. Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated - I've been stuck on this for a while!

Comment: whats the range you want to apply this smush? whole or partial?

Comment: 'Raw Data'!AL3:AY3, which is being referenced from 'Processed Data'!O3
So to clarify, I would need to be referencing 'Raw Data'!AL3:AY3 to grab the schools, and show them in 'Processed Data'!O3:V3, but for every single row automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the part you are interested in is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF('Raw Data'!AL3:AY8<>"", 
 SUBSTITUTE('Raw Data'!AL3:AY8, " ", "♠"), )), , 999^99)), " "), "♠", " "))
```

[image: 0]

- but you could have it all in one-cell solution:

```
={{"Timestamp (mm/dd/yyyy)", "Duplicate", "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone", 
  "Email Address", "Zip Code", "Parent/Guardian", "Teacher", "Administrator",
  "Elected Official", "Community Member", "Business Organization", "Non-Profit Organization",
  "Affiliated_School_1", "Affiliated_School_2", "Affiliated_School_3", "Affiliated_School_4", 
  "Affiliated_School_5", "Affiliated_School_6", "Affiliated_School_7", "Affiliated_School_8",
  "BeCampusRep"}; {QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN('Raw Data'!A3:A), {'Raw Data'!C3:G, 'Raw Data'!AC3:AK,
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF('Raw Data'!AL3:AY<>"", 
 SUBSTITUTE('Raw Data'!AL3:AY, " ", "♠"), )), , 999^99)), " "), "♠", " "), IF(
 MIN(8-MMULT(LEN(IF('Raw Data'!AL3:AY<>"", "♦", )), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN('Raw Data'!AL3:AY))^0))>0,
 IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(LEN('Raw Data'!A3:A), REPT(" ♣", 
 MIN(8-MMULT(LEN(IF('Raw Data'!AL3:AY<>"", "♦", )), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN('Raw Data'!AL3:AY))^0))), ), "♣")),
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(LEN('Raw Data'!A3:A), REPT(" ♣", 
 MIN(8-MMULT(LEN(IF('Raw Data'!AL3:AY<>"", "♦", )), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN('Raw Data'!AL3:AY))^0))), ), "♣")),
 COUNTBLANK('Raw Data'!A1:A)+COUNTA('Raw Data'!A1:A)-1, )), 'Raw Data'!AZ3:AZ}, )), "where Col1 !=''")}}
```

[image: 0]

- ### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nhRIUjSy9d6cclnSIdH5UMsKoNbnSeUjs4TQJI2BpZs/edit#gid=393227070)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked wonderfully.