# Go into "Display" tab, click a name off the drop down list, and view that individual's data

Tags: worksheet-function, vlookup, google-sheets

I have 3 tabs. "Timestamps" "Techs/Locations" and "Display."

My form timestamps when an employee clocks in or out. I have created two separate columns to carry over the date and time from the timestamp column (which is hidden)

The form set up my sheet to have columns B:AA as each location.

As a clock in/out is performed, it records the name under the corresponding location's column.

I want to carry over the data of the employee of my choice has onto my DISPLAY sheet. I have tried `Vlookup`, but it only searches in the FIRST column. I have 26 COLUMNS. There is no way around the number of columns I have discovered.

I have tried `INDEX`/`MATCH`, Query, etc. The DISPLAY sheet has a drop down list of the employees. I wanted to do something such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,Timestamps!B2:AE,{27,28,29,30})
```

Here is a link to an identical sheet with all information shortened and changed:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U3ZBCI8tHObUNa7dUv6j04-syd0EkOMD8e3yyQ3SVL4/edit?gid=301227841

Again, I want to be able to go into "Display" tab, click a name off the drop down list, and view that individual's data- which would be pulled from "timestamps."

Comment: Please add a brief description on your search/research efforts as is suggested in [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Also note that your shared spreadsheet is in your trash. Do you plan to substitute another spreadsheet?

Comment: Have you considered this topic: [Grabbing only non-empty cells from a row range for every row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/127762/196152). .